Archivo dañado al descargar con PHP
tengo el siguiente problema cuando trato de descargar archivos comprimidos en .Zip en PHP el codigo parece funcionar, el peso del archivo lo muestra pero cuando trato de abrir el archivo para descomprimir me aparece lo siguiente:

Parece que el archivo se descarga dañado, este es mi codigo en PHP
`<?php
// Configuración de la base de datos
$host = '';
$db = '';
$user = '';
$pass = '';

session_start();
$id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario']; // Obtiene el id_usuario de la sesión

try {
// Conexión a la base de datos
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// ID del usuario
$id_usuario = 1; // Cambia esto si necesitas descargar archivos de otro usuario

// Consultar los archivos del usuario específico
$sql = "SELECT archivoPDF, archivoJSON FROM facturas WHERE id_usuario = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$id_usuario]);
$archivos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Crear archivo .zip
$zipFile = 'archivos_descargados.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) {
    die("No se pudo abrir el archivo <$zipFile>\n");
}

// Agregar archivos al zip
foreach ($archivos as $archivo) {
    $pdfPath = $archivo['archivoPDF'];
    $jsonPath = $archivo['archivoJSON'];

    // Imprimir las rutas de los archivos
    echo "Verificando: $pdfPath\n"; // Mensaje de depuración
    echo "Verificando: $jsonPath\n"; // Mensaje de depuración

    // Verificar que los archivos existan antes de agregarlos
    if (file_exists($pdfPath)) {
        $zip->addFile($pdfPath, basename($pdfPath));
    } else {
        echo "Archivo no encontrado: $pdfPath\n"; // Mensaje de error
    }

    if (file_exists($jsonPath)) {
        $zip->addFile($jsonPath, basename($jsonPath));
    } else {
        echo "Archivo no encontrado: $jsonPath\n"; // Mensaje de error
    }
}

// Cerrar el zip
$zip->close();

// Descargar el archivo .zip
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($zipFile) . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipFile));
readfile($zipFile);

// Eliminar el archivo .zip después de la descarga
unlink($zipFile);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>`

Explicando un poco mas el codigo yo inserto dos URL desde postman a una base de datos de un servidor de AWS luego quiero descargar los dos archivos comprimidos mediante la URL con un archivo no tengo problemas pero cuando son archivos comprimidos pues recivo este error, de antemano muchas gracias!
codigo con los echo comentados
    <?php
// Configuración de la base de datos
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'facturacion_electronica';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'Nicole_07';

session_start();
$id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario']; // Obtiene el id_usuario de la sesión

try {
    // Conexión a la base de datos
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   // ID del usuario
    $id_usuario = 1; // Cambia esto si necesitas descargar archivos de otro usuario

    // Consultar los archivos del usuario específico
    $sql = "SELECT archivoPDF, archivoJSON FROM facturas WHERE id_usuario = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$id_usuario]);
    $archivos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Crear archivo .zip
    $zipFile = 'archivos_descargados.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if ($zip->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) {
        die("No se pudo abrir el archivo <$zipFile>\n");
    }

    // Agregar archivos al zip
    foreach ($archivos as $archivo) {
        $pdfPath = $archivo['archivoPDF'];
        $jsonPath = $archivo['archivoJSON'];

        // Imprimir las rutas de los archivos
        //echo "Verificando: $pdfPath\n"; // Mensaje de depuración
        //echo "Verificando: $jsonPath\n"; // Mensaje de depuración

        // Verificar que los archivos existan antes de agregarlos
        if (file_exists($pdfPath)) {
            $zip->addFile($pdfPath, basename($pdfPath));
        } else {
            //echo "Archivo no encontrado: $pdfPath\n"; // Mensaje de error
        }

        if (file_exists($jsonPath)) {
            $zip->addFile($jsonPath, basename($jsonPath));
        } else {
            //echo "Archivo no encontrado: $jsonPath\n"; // Mensaje de error
        }
    }

    // Cerrar el zip
    $zip->close();

    // Descargar el archivo .zip
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($zipFile) . '"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipFile));
    readfile($zipFile);

    // Eliminar el archivo .zip después de la descarga
    unlink($zipFile);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //echo "Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>

Resolver el problema

@Excorpion es curioso, si comento todos los echo el archivo de descarga con 0 bytes

@Excorpion me refiero a que el archivo ahora no tiene peso y de igual forma sigue corrupto

@Excorpion exacto son dos cosas distintas el archivo normalmente no tiene este problema de hecho lo descarga con el peso adecuado, eso significa que se pudieron comprimir, pero el problema es que no lo puedo abrir porque el archivo parece estar dañada

@Excorpion si, ya lo hice y ahora muestra ambos problemas muestras, cuando comento todos los echo me muestra el archivo con 0 bytes y tambien esta corrupto

@Excorpion ya agregue el codigo con todos los echo comentados

Previo a esta respuesta, solicité al usuario comentar los echo, ya que interrumpen la salida del zip. Esto generó cambios, pero no solucionó el problema original.

Disculpa la demora, pero estaba buscando las funciones para realizar lo siguiente:
Limpiar el buffer de salida
Para asegurar que no haya contenido en el buffer de salida, usaremos ob_clean() y flush(), antes de la descarga del archivo. Verifica que los nombres de los archivos, no contengan espacios extras durante el filename.
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. basename($zipFile) .'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipFile));

ob_clean(); // Limpiar cualquier salida previa
flush(); // Vaciar el buffer de salida

readfile($zipFile); 

También para poder obtener la información de los echo sin usar estos, ya que pueden interferir con el archivo, usaremos un archivo como log.
Asi que reemplzada los echo por file_put_contents, esto generará un archivo a modo de log, para obtener los mensajes deseados. Acá un ejemplo
file_put_contents('log.txt', "Archivo PDF no encontrado: $pdfPath\n", FILE_APPEND);

Y por último, luego de cerrar el zip, comprueba que este se ha generado correctamente y con peso.
//Cerrar el zip
$zip->close();

//Verificar si el zip fue creado y tiene contenido
if (!file_exists($zipFile) || filesize($zipFile) == 0) {
    die("Error: El archivo ZIP no se creó correctamente o está vacío. FileExist: " . file_exists($zipFile) . " FileSize: " . filesize($zipFile));
}

Prueba a corregir y debugear tu código nuevamente, con estos cambios.

logre arreglar el error creando un nuevo codigo
  <?php
    // Habilitar la visualización de errores
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    // Configuración de la base de datos
    $host = '';
    $db = '';
    $user = '';
    $pass = '';
    
    session_start();
    $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario']; // Obtiene el id_usuario de la sesión
    
    // Crear un archivo .zip
    $zip_file = "/var/www/html/uploads/archivos_usuario_$id_usuario.zip"; // Ruta absoluta
    touch($zip_file);
    
    // Abrir el archivo zip
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $this_zip = $zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
    
    if ($this_zip !== true) {
        die("No se pudo abrir el archivo zip. Código de error: $this_zip");
    }
    
    // Conexión a la base de datos
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
        // Consultar los archivos del usuario específico
        $sql = "SELECT archivoPDF, archivoJSON FROM facturas WHERE id_usuario = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$id_usuario]);
    
        $archivos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($archivos); // Verifica que se estén recuperando los archivos
    
        // Agregar archivos al zip
        foreach ($archivos as $archivo) {
            $pdfUrl = $archivo['archivoPDF'];
            $jsonUrl = $archivo['archivoJSON'];
    
            // Ruta temporal para almacenar los archivos descargados
            $tempPdfPath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'pdf_');
            $tempJsonPath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'json_');
    
            // Descargar el archivo PDF
            if (file_put_contents($tempPdfPath, file_get_contents($pdfUrl))) {
                $zip->addFile($tempPdfPath, basename($pdfUrl));
            } else {
                echo "Error al descargar el archivo PDF: $pdfUrl\n"; // Mensaje de error
            }
    
            // Descargar el archivo JSON
            if (file_put_contents($tempJsonPath, file_get_contents($jsonUrl))) {
                $zip->addFile($tempJsonPath, basename($jsonUrl));
            } else {
                echo "Error al descargar el archivo JSON: $jsonUrl\n"; // Mensaje de error
            }
        }
    
        // Cerrar el zip
        $zip->close();
    
        // Descargar el archivo .zip
        if (file_exists($zip_file)) {
            $demo_name = "archivos_usuario_$id_usuario.zip";
            header('Content-type: application/zip');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $demo_name . '"');
            readfile($zip_file);
    
            // Eliminar el archivo .zip después de la descarga
            unlink($zip_file);
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>


No conseguiste el error del primer código?
